# Getting Image from a Stream (WMS)

Tags: image, stream, windows-phone-8.1, wms

I'm developing a Window Phone 8.1 app. I'm trying to get an image from a Web Map Service and show it in a MapControl. I already get the stream with a http request and now I want to transform it in an Image.

How can I do this part? This is what I have:

**Downloading the Stream:**

```
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
HttpResponseMessage request = await httpClient.GetAsync("<URL>").ConfigureAwait(false);
Stream stream = await request.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Now I have the correct Stream from the request (it's a png image). Now I want to transform it in an `Image`. I already tried to use the `FromStream()` method but it seems that it's not supported in WP 8.1.

Can you help me please with this last part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this

```
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
HttpResponseMessage request = await httpClient.GetAsync("URL").ConfigureAwait(false);

using (Stream stream = await request.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().ConfigureAwait(false))
{
    MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
    await stream.CopyToAsync(memStream);
    memStream.Position = 0;

    CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
        {
            BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage();

            bitmap.SetSource(memStream.AsRandomAccessStream());
            img.Source = bitmap;

            memStream.Dispose();
        }
    );
}
```

where *img* is an Image object defined in XAML.

BTW, a simple

```
<Image Source="URL" />
```

in XAML would also probably work for you if all you need is a bitmap as a source for Image.